# Duplicate record script | Efficiency boost

Tags: mysql

I have devised a script to search through my table for duplicate records and display their count.

I am wondering if there is a way to improve the efficiency of the search, given the current search takes 7 seconds. Here's the code:

```
use gameStore;
select ID, count(*) as idRepl, 
console, count(*) as consoleRepl, 
price, count(*) as priceRepl,
purchased, count(*) as purchRepl from wishlist
group by console, price, purchased having count(*) > 1;
```

---

**EDIT 1**

EXPLAIN RESULTS

```
FIELD     |TYPE       |NULL|Key    |DEFAULT|Extra
ID        |INT        |NO  |PRI    |       |auto_increment
console   |VARCHAR(50)|NO  |       |       |
Price     |FLOAT      |YES |       |NULL   |
Purchased |VARCHAR(4) |YES |       |NO     |
```

Comment: Do you have index on (console, price, purchased) ? Add EXPLAIN for your select and CREATE TABLE. Note: all those counts are gonna return the same number AFAIK.

Comment: @user1786423 ID is the primary key (to be amended as  inherited table).

The basic idea is to display 1 instance of each duplicate. So if a row has 5 other exact copies, only the one is shown

Comment: Why are there 4 identical `count(*)` in the select list?

Comment: @ypercube how do you mean? for each column? Each has a different name

Comment: @MichaelWiggins [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) works on queries too - showing execution plan for the query. Count(*) will return always the same number, only with different names.

Comment: @user1786423 That;t the point, it will find how many that exact row is present in the table from my understanding, unless I'm mistaken =/

Comment: @MichaelWiggins different names they may have, they all going to show the same result. What exactly do you expect/want them to show?

Comment: @MichaelWiggins then there is not reason to select the same number three times. "count(*) as consoleRepl" takes the count and aliases it with consoleRepl, it is totally independent from console column noted on the same line, other instances of count(*) will return the same number only alias it with different name.

Comment: And that's not the `EXPLAIN` ouptut you showed us, that's the `describe table` output.

Comment: As @user1786423 has already suggested, add an index on `(console, price, purchased)`, for the query to be more efficient. (user1786423, you can add that as an answer.)

Comment: Many thanks, I need to rebuild the table anyway so may as well do it correctly this time round :£

Comment: @ypercube seemed a trivial question added to asking for explain etc. but I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The troubles with count aside, probably simplest way to make that query fast is adding multicolumn index

```
(console, price, purchased)
```

if table wishlist is InnoDB and ID is primary key or

```
(console, price, purchased, ID)
```

if table wishlist is MyISAM.

Such index is enough to [cover the query](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/).

Comment: Good find, thanks for that, It'll be helpful for the future :3